# error while unmarshalling "Type mismatch: cannot convert from XmlAccessType to AccessType "

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am working with Jaxb, Unmarshalling an xml. I am using java 1.6. This is the class which is generated through JWSDP 2.0. (xjc.bat) but what my problem is i am unable to compile the generated class. i am getting an syntax error as shown below.

> **"Type mismatch: cannot convert from XmlAccessType to AccessType"**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)// here i am getting sytax error
@XmlType(name = "personinfo", propOrder = {
    "firstname",
    "lastname",
    "address"
})
public class Personinfo {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String firstname;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String lastname;
    @XmlElement(name = "Address", required = true)
    protected PersonAddress address;
............................
```

can any one help in this regard,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the `Personinfo` class from your question with the demo code below and everything worked correctly.  Since you are using Java SE 6 (which includes a JAXB implementation) you will want to make sure you don't have any of the JAXB APIs from the JWSDP 2.0 on your class path.

I would also recommend using the XJC utility from Java SE 6 instead of JWSDP, as JWSDP is quite old:

- http://java.sun.com/webservices/downloads/previous/webservicespack.jsp

**Demo**

```
package forum10514244;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Personinfo.class);

        File xml = new File("src/forum10514244/input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Personinfo> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xml), Personinfo.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <firstname>Jane</firstname>
    <lastname>Doe</lastname>
    <Address/>
</root>
```